# Zentyal dpkg dependecy install problems because packages are not configured

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have done a fresh install of Zentyal 3.5, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04. To be fully operational, several modules must be installed. Many of these modules failed to install since a chain of them cannot be configured. An example error is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zentyal-ntp:
    zentyal-ntp depends on zentyal-firewall; however:
        Package zentyal-firewall is not configured yet.
```

I have tried removing the packages and their configurations with `sudo apt-get purge [PACKAGE]`. Re-installing them was not successful after this.

How can I install these packages?

Comment: What does `dpkg -l zentyal-firewall` show?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message is clear:

```
Package zentyal-firewall is not configured yet
```

You need to configure it first, so you can continue with the installation:

```
sudo dpkg --configure zentyal-firewall
```

I would guess that there's a problem with the package itself so it can't be configured, in which case, you need to read the messages and solve it.

I would also run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install` to make sure other problems that this half-configured state could caused.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problems with the **Live installer** for v3.5 in 32 or 64 bits. The **Ubuntu's repositories of Zentyal seems to be broken** ([bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zentyal-core/+bug/1310694)) as for today (October 2014), so we must use the reseller ones.

I have finally solved it by directly installing **Ubuntu Server** and doing:

- Add the Zentyal official repository (for v3.5 in my case):

  deb http://archive.zentyal.org/zentyal 3.5 main extra
- Import publick key:

  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 10E239FF
  wget -q http://keys.zentyal.org/zentyal-3.5-archive.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
- Update repositories:

  sudo apt-get update
- And then install zentyal from that new repository:

  sudo apt-get install zentyal

(Note that the package `zentyal` is not, as for today, on official Ubuntu repositories, so it will be installed from the official Zentyal ones)

Tested working on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Server.